# Replace decode the url in JavaScript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

How can I decode a url in JavaScript or JQuery?

---

**An example:** I've got this url:

> http://localhost:8080/map/file.html?var1=a%20b%20c&var2=d%20e%20f

If I use code below,

```js
var str = "var1=a%20b%20c&var2=d%20e%20f";
document.write(str.replace("%20", " "));
```

I've got this:

> http://localhost:8080/map/file.html?var1=a b%20c&var2=d%20e%20f

What is the fast en the best way to decode the url?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: @Juhana While that does do what the OP is asking, I think Tushar's answer is probably what the OP actually needs

Comment: Yeah, although the actual problem has more than its share of duplicates too...

Comment: Tushars answer is the correct one, since it is a URL and you are trying to decode the encoded URI

Comment: @Juhana: I've edit my question, it was not so clear that is was an url

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

```
var str = decodeURIComponent("This%20is%20a%20%string");
```

As the string is URL-encoded, the last occurrence of `%20` contains an extra `%` after it, which is probably a **typo**.

```js
var str = decodeURIComponent("This%20is%20a%20string");
document.write(str);
```

---

**EDIT:**

```js
var url = "http://localhost:8080/map/file.html?var1=a%20b%20c&var2=d%20e%20f";
document.write(decodeURIComponent(url));
```

Comment: This will fail due to `%20%`

Comment: @AlexK. I guess that is copy-paste error as the string is clearly encoded string.

Comment: Well that's not an actual URI Component then.

Comment: and it will replace a ton off other stuff, wich he might not know

Comment: Aye it probably is a typo, but worth mentioning

Comment: @EasyBB he didnt ask for replacing an URI Component

Comment: From the looks of the question, this would be the real answer. Now if the OP did not want to use `%20` as an example they should change the question.

Comment: @CodeiSir That's because this is probably an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and Tushar's answer deals with the actual underlying issue, not the immediate need.

Comment: @JamesThorpe but then you still have to explain it - like this it might only confuse him. This is the kind of answers that are made AS FAST AS POSSIBLE to earn Credits, not to provide a good solution

Comment: @CodeiSir though I agree with you, which is why I gave you the upvote and marked this question as a duplicate. This from seeing `%20` which everyone knows is a space in the URI, so we'd automagically assume it is decoding.

Comment: I expected this as well, that why I gave you an upvote ;)

Answer (score 3):

You are only replacing the first element. Use this RegEx with g to replace all:

```
var str = "This%20is%20a%20%string";
console.log(str.replace(/%20/g, " ");
```

EDIT: as after your edit it appears, you want to unescape an URI use `decodeURIComponent()` as first suggested by @EasyBB

Comment: as for this answer `g` is a global modifier of the RegExp expressions. Just like there is `m` == multiline, `i` == case insensitive...